# Infinite Login Loop after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, login

Dell Precision 7730, Intel i9, 64gb RAM, 2x 500GB SSD.  Straight-up Ubuntu.
Just tried upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04.03, and facing an infinite login loop after it said it couldn't complete the install and my system may be unstable.  It made no mention of *what* it couldn't complete.

I do not have NVidia

I am not in a dual boot situation

What I have tried with no successful results:

Using lightdm - Fails with iwlwifi WGDS but not WRDS BIOS error (even after recovery and turning on networking)

Edited /etc/default/grub file removing, one at a time, both quiet and splash with reboots in between, and trying both quiet and splash alone.

Did the apt-get update & apt-get upgrade things -- nothing to update or upgrade

Did the apt-get autoremove

Did the apt dist-upgrade thing -- Said there was nothing to do

No matter what I do with apt on updating, reinstalling or what-have-you, everything says it is up to date.

All disks and partitions are error free, fsck is good.

Removed .Xauthority files

Replaced .Xauthority with old backup

There does seem to be an segmentation fault in XORG (following startx) with a final:
xinit: unable to connect to x server: Connection refused

So, reinstalled xauth, xorg and Ubuntu Desktop

Probably read another 100 suggestions but they are extremely dated, apply to NVidia or other distros, or are effectively duplicate suggestions.

I can run Focal Fossa from a USB Live Disk, so my computer, graphics, cards, drives, etc is capable of it (I say drives because I used the discs utility to ...again... check the health of the partitions), and I can access all the files. (I do have full backup of home directory).

What I cannot seem to do is to re-install 20.04 from the live disc without a total reformat. The only options I have is to re-install with total file loss, erase and re-install with total file loss, or reinstall 20.04 alongside 20.04, which isn't a solution because there is no need to switch between an empty working copy and an "all-my-stuff-is-there" broken copy.

No doubt it seems to be XORG, but not sure how to fix.

Please help.

Comment: who owns your home directory?  what's the user ID? what's the userID in /etc/passwd?

Comment: 'root' owns "home" (755).  But my  home directory is owned by me, which matches the response from 'echo $USER'.  My user name is also in /etc/passwd, along with all the other users.  My id is 1001, which also matches the files in home from 'll -n'.  This is also true of .Xauthority (my id as 1001).

Answer (score 0):

So, after plugging through XORG docs for hours, I decided to check the distro upgrade logs and found one little line stating my AMD GPU drivers failed to update properly.

Had to uninstall the drivers completely (which also gave me a bit of trouble), but finally came through.

Followed the instructions to fix it here:

[AMD GPU Installation and Configuratoin](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln311165/installing-and-configuring-amdgpu-pro-in-ubuntu-16-04-linux?lang=en)